# Hash a whole object without converting to byte[] first

Tags: java, hash, sha256

I want to get sha2 hash of particular java object. I don't want it to be `int`, I want `byte[]` or at least `String`. I've got the following code to create sha2:

```
static byte[] sha2(byte[] message) {
    if (message == null || message.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("message is null");
    }
    try {
        MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA_256);
        return sha256.digest(message);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```

I can just convert my object to `byte[]`, but I don't think it's a good idea to store big array in memory just to create 32 byte array. So how can I compute sha2(or maybe another crypto hash function) of object?

Comment: This screams XY-problem. Why do you need to hash an *object*? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to load the whole object into memory, you can load parts of it into temporary buffer.

Dump object into a temporary file using FileOutputStream/BufferedOutputStream, this will make sure serialized object does not pollute JVM memory.

The load serialize object from temporary file using FileInputStream/BufferedInputStream and feed it to `MessageDigest#update(buf)` method in a loop.

Finally call `MessageDigest#digest()` to finish work:

```
int[] buf = new int[1024];
while (/* has more data */) {
    int readBytes = readIntoBuf(buf);
    sha256.update(buf, 0, readBytes);
}
return sha256.digest();
```

If you can afford to store entire serialized object in memory, use `ByteArrayOutputStream` and pass result byte[] to `MessageDigest#digest(buf)`:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOuputStream(baos)) {
    oos.writeObject(obj);

    MessageDigest sha256 = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA_256);
    return sha256.digest(baos.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: This is actually another question, but anyway. How can read an object like this?

Comment: Do you serialize it?

Comment: Yes, I do. I use ObjectOutputStream#writeObject with no buffers at all.

Comment: If your java object really big then dump it into a temp file and then feed it via input stream to the code above.

Comment: You should be able to it read as bytes using InputStream / BufferedInputStream

Comment: @hoaz, it's not really big: one little map and few UUIDs

Comment: Then just use ByteOutputStream in combination with method you have provided in your question.

Comment: Can you please provide some code how to read an object into buffer? Because I don't think that ByteOutputStream is good for me.

Comment: @Tony: You're contradicting yourself. You've said it's not really big, so why not use ByteArrayOutputStream?

Comment: Added ByteArrayOutputStream sample

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: So what exactly you were looking for?